# Auto save changed text in richtextbox to database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created one simple note taking application in jquery & php.
Current functionality is like when user clicks save button it sends a ajax request with complete data to update it in db(mysql).
All works well. But now I want to auto save only changed text while user typing. 
I don't want to send entire text to server again and again in text change event.
It should send only text which has changed.

For Ex:
    **This is saved text.**

When user continues typing.
    **This is saved text. *Unsaved text..***

It should be able to send only "***Unsaved text..***" to server to update in db.

How can i implement this in jquery & server side script.?
 Any Idea..?

Comment: But then what will you do when user *removes* text? Your general direction would be looking for a plugin or library that lets you compare 2 complex strings and return the difference - but you'll have to look deeper in your logic in how to implement text remove/change

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Then it should also update in database.

Comment: It's difficult to handle this when a user add/remove/change text. Do you really need this? Are you expecting this field will be so large that this will be needed?

Comment: Yes I need exactly like this. you can find the same functionality here http://simple-note.appspot.com... but i have no idea how they  have implimented.

Comment: Check the DB for which text was there before, if anything has changed, update it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a good idea. First of all why do you want this functionality? Just for fun, I saw it somewhere and thought that it will be cool is not really valid. One of the valid reason I see is that the notes will be huge and you do not like to send them constantly to a server. But you have to understand that with a text note it is hard to get a huge note. You have to type a lot in order to surpass 1KB.

If you really need it, you have to handle finding changes on a client and on the server. On a client you have to find what has changed (and taking into the account how much time have you spent thinking about a question, I highly doubt you can do this). It is not just adding new text in the end. What if person will:

- add the text in the middle
- remove some text
- substitute a string with another string
- make multiple above-mentioned things

Even if you will do this, when you receive this info on the server, you have to write a logic to change your field in the database. And it will be much harder than just simple update.

So my thoughts about this: do not over complicate things.

If you afraid that the person will lose his changes and do not want to send new draft to the server every time a user added/deleted few chars, than save it locally with the help of localstorage (html5 localshorage) or cookies and build your client side logic upon this.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to make the richtextbox a [Content Editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) div containing a simplified HTML markup so that when you add something it appears in a span like this:

```
<span class="changed added" data-pos"23">new text</span>
```

where `data-pos` is the location of the inserted text in the textbox and when you delete something it appears in a span like this:

```
<span class="changed deleted">deleted text</span>
```

That way when you click save you can send only the changed text `$('#richtextbox span.changed')` back to the server for processing. Then the server can do a string replace to add or remove the text as needed from the original text in the database.

Comment: @user2519407 With an response/attitude like that you will be hard pressed to find help. Good luck figuring it out!

Comment: :-) Yes my response looks bit rude. Sorry for that.
But I had acknowledged your idea.. i worked on it but later it doesn't seem to work as excepted. Anyway thanks for your timely answer & help.. and sorry again. :-)